# Check a sequence inside another sequence in matlab

Tags: matlab

I have some sequences:

```
{B < A < C < D < E}, 
{A < B < D < E < C}
```

How to check `B < E` in the above strings or not?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`regexp`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/regexp.html):

```
inputs = {'{B < A < C < D < E}', '{A < B < D < E < C}' };
res = regexp( inputs, 'B.*<.*E' )
```

Results with

```
res = 
[2]    [6]
```

That is `res{ii}` is the first location of `B` in the input string `ii`. If `res{ii}` is empty it means `B < E` is not in the `ii`-th string.

Comment: what do  [2] and [6] mean ? Thanks

Comment: @kgk please read the linked documentation of `regexp` for more details. In short, `regexp` searches for a pattern (`'B<E'`) in a string (`inputs`) and returns the index of the begginging of the pattern in each input string. In this example it's the location of `'B'` in each of the input strings.